# Android pop-up keyboard hiding last form field when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iscroll4

I am using iScroll 4 on Android. I am facing the following problem:

When I click the last form field, the Android popup keyboard hides the form field.

Here is the link to iScroll: http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Can anyone help me find a way to solve this problem, ideally using javascript?